# Problema com retorno de função

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Galera, tenho um código json que busca informações do usuário logado, e posteriormente, tenho um outro código que busca todos os setores cadastrados no sistema. A função retorna normalmente as informações, porém quando retorno o valor desejado na função sempre vai como `undefined`. Segue abaixo o código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=radio]").bind("click", function () {
            if ($("input[type=radio]:checked").val() == "Privado") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetSetores", "Json")",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar os setores!");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = "";
                        var idSetorUsuarioLogado = setorUsuarioLogado();
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            if (item.Id == idSetorUsuarioLogado) {
                                items += "<div><input type='checkbox' class='setores' name='setors' value='" + item.Id + "' id='SetoresAcesso' checked>" + item.Nome + "</div>";
                            } else {
                                items += "<div><input type='checkbox' class='setores' name='setors' value='" + item.Id + "' id='SetoresAcesso'>" + item.Nome + "</div>";
                            }
                        });
                        $('#ListaDeSetores').html(items);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#Setor').html('');
            }
        });
    });

    function setorUsuarioLogado() {
        var idSetorUsuarioLogado;
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CarregaDadosUsuario", "Json")",
            type: "GET",
            error: function () {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar o setor do usuário logado");
            },
            success: function (resultado) {
                idSetorUsuarioLogado = parseInt(resultado.IdSetor);
            }
        });
        return idSetorUsuarioLogado;
    }
```

Comment: se voce fizer um console.log no resultado.IdSetor dentro do success o valor vai aparecer ? se sim provavelmente o return esteja executando antes de ocorrer o success, se for isso tente dar o return dentro ou criar uma variavel global e atribuir esse resultado a ela que resolvera o problema...

Comment: recomendo que de uma lida nesse post, pelo que me parece e o mesmo problema que o seu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Comment: não poderia retornar o resultado de "setorUsuarioLogado" juntamente com os dados da primeira requsição? Asssim evitaria uma nova requisição e eliminaria o problema.

Comment: Em qual ponto específico (linha) do código o erro está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data) {
    var items = "";
    var idSetorUsuarioLogado = setorUsuarioLogado();

    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each(json, function() {

      $.each(this, function(i, item) {

        if (item.Id == idSetorUsuarioLogado) {
            items += "<div><input type='checkbox' class='setores' name='setors' value='" + item.Id + "' id='SetoresAcesso' checked>" + item.Nome + "</div>";
        } else {
            items += "<div><input type='checkbox' class='setores' name='setors' value='" + item.Id + "' id='SetoresAcesso'>" + item.Nome + "</div>";
        }

      });

    });

}
```

Tente dessa forma o "sucess".